# How to go to second page or next page in the search results using XPATH

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Well...I think I still haven't figured out how `xpath` works. I am trying to select the below element so that I can click on the second page. But what I am trying does not work. What is wrong here? I am selecting the `a` tag and then trying to find the one which contains `ref` whose value is `next`.

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@ref,'next')]"));
```

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the `html` here @Zack?

Comment: Or provide a link to the web site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably see a typo there. The `attribute` you are trying to use is `rel` which has value `next`

So the correct `xpath` will be

```
//a[contains(@rel,'next')]
```

Comment: Aha...My bad! Thanks @Saifur. It was indeed a typo !